# Nanoexpress server fails on Heroku & AWS - runs fine locally - cannot trace 'dest.on()' error

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, amazon-ec2, nanoexpress

Relevant stack-trace below - from Heroku:

```
2020-04-28T17:49:11.997756+00:00 app[web.1]: Your app is listening on port 14385
2020-04-28T17:49:12.491486+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-28T17:49:41.748150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-04-28T17:49:41.649885+00:00 app[web.1]: _stream_readable.js:660
2020-04-28T17:49:41.649896+00:00 app[web.1]: dest.on('unpipe', onunpipe);
2020-04-28T17:49:41.649897+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-04-28T17:49:41.649897+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-28T17:49:41.649898+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: dest.on is not a function
2020-04-28T17:49:41.649899+00:00 app[web.1]: at ReadStream.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:660:8)
2020-04-28T17:49:41.649900+00:00 app[web.1]: at SendStream.stream (/app/node_modules/send/index.js:798:10)
2020-04-28T17:49:41.649900+00:00 app[web.1]: at SendStream.send (/app/node_modules/send/index.js:707:8)
2020-04-28T17:49:41.649900+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/send/index.js:774:12
2020-04-28T17:49:41.649901+00:00 app[web.1]: at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:172:5)
```

From AWS (EC2 using a Bitnami instance for NodeJS apps):

```
Your app is listening on port 8080
_stream_readable.js:666
  dest.on('unpipe', onunpipe);
       ^

TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at ReadStream.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:666:8)
    at SendStream.stream (/opt/bitnami/apps/demo/htdocs/node_modules/send/index.js:798:10)
    at SendStream.send (/opt/bitnami/apps/demo/htdocs/node_modules/send/index.js:707:8)
    at /opt/bitnami/apps/coronavirus-demo/htdocs/node_modules/send/index.js:774:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:5)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #1
```

I see that we seem to be dying on _stream_readable.js:666 where 'dest.on' isn't defined - and I'm way into the weeds of Node at this point - so I'm not sure what I'm looking for, but I find that we're defining this method further down in the file:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js:852 -

Is this as simple as we're evaluating this _stream_readable file top-down and we haven't defined on() as of line 666 and that's why it's failing?

But why would it work locally?  The app runs fine with Nanoexpress server on a Macbook Pro - same package.json and lock files - no devDependencies that make any difference (the only devDependencies are like Mocha and Sinon and Chai for tests)

I've run the app locally with NODE_ENV=production and NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true (it's a React & Express [Nanoexpress] app) and it boots and I can get what I need running just fine.

It's only when I push to Heroku / AWS that I'm getting this failure.  Feels like we're trying to use a function before it's defined...

Answer (score 0):

nanoexpress author here.

nanoexpress works fine on Heroku on my projects, but on AWS did not test, but nanoexpress does not support Lambda/Serverless.

Please check first your code or try PRO version as now it's Free